# React Refs' value not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a very simple example. I have a form and I need the value of a hidden field so I need to use `ref`:

```
<form>
 <input ref="num" type="hidden" name="amount" value="99"/>
</form>

var number = this.refs.num.value;

console.log(number); // nothing
console.log(this.refs.num); // shows the field
```

How to get the value with ref?

Comment: `this.refs.num.value` is correct. Could you provide a bit more context to your code? Where are you trying to grab `this.refs`?

Comment: @BradColthurst From a function. `foo: function(){...}`

Comment: And where are you calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get value, before rendering, try this:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  if (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  var value = this.refs.num.value;
  console.log(value);
}

render() {
  console.log(this.refs.num ? this.refs.num.value : '');
  return (
    <form>
      <input ref="num" type="hidden" name="amount" value="99" />
      <a onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>submit</a> 
    </form>
  );
}
```

output would be empty string at first and 99 after render:

Comment: Hi. How to get the 99 when I call my function?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Crema/pen/yOdqpO?editors=1011 on this codePen I have no problem getting the value from a function

Comment: I've wrote a handleSubmit function

Comment: Thanks. I needed the `.bind(this)`. ;) Thanks again.